# Indicate Loading In Browser When Downloading File

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

On our web application, we have loads of attachments, some static (from DB) and some dynamic (generated), some of the generated files take really long (`Content-Disposition: Attachment`)
to download, and the user will click away sometimes. is there anyway to show and **HIDE** a loader as soon as the file is actually served to the browser?

I have looked for similar questions on stackoverflow and there are, but none of them with useful answers: for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283058/how-to-display-and-remove-a-loading-gif-when-downloading-a-file).

Is this a viable question or should i just try to increase the speed at which the files are generated?

Comment: Is this the delay between clicking the link and generating the file, or the actual downloading of a file?

Comment: It is the delay between clicking and the file-download dialog box showing.

Comment: Duplicate with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that you can use the following post from this community:-

[JavaScript/jQuery to download file via POST with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499597/javascript-jquery-to-download-file-via-post-with-json-data)

Use javascript post method that I mentioned first.
Hope this finally answers your question. :)

Comment: i will use this solution, thanks for the input, im upvoting all your answers for your assistance,

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax code for doing form submit. While the server processes the request, show a div with loading icon at top of the page.

Write following code in your jsp.

```
<div  id="submitPage">
  <img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="">Submitting order...
</div>
```

initially hide it by using this code

```
$('#submitPage').hide();
```

and on click of your submit button just show it.

```
$('#submitPage').show();
```

Hide it again when ajax response comes.

Hope it solves your problem.

Regards,
Lav

Comment: Thanks Lav, I have tried this but the page sending the request does not reload (hence the loading will not hide again), and an ajax request does not start up the download-dialog

Answer (score 2):

you need not load the page again. Simply play around with the ajax call with a bit of javascript manipulation. :)

```
$('#submitPage').show();

var url = "urlUsed";

$.post(url, $("#formName").serialize() , function(responseValue){                   

    $('#submitPage').hide();

});
```

If not this way, you can change ajax call as :-

```
function functionName(){
    ajaxRequest = createXMLHttpRequest(); 
    var url = "urlUsed";
    $('#submitPage').show();
    ajaxRequest.open('get', url , true);
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = processAjaxResponseForMethodName;
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
}

function processAjaxResponseForMethodName(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {  
           $('#submitPage').hide();

    }
}
```

Comment: It works (makes request to server and hides the loading) but the file data is now in ajaxRequest.responseText and is not 'downloaded' to the onscreen download file dialog. see this link : http://groups.google.com/group/ajax-world/browse_thread/thread/b7abc61c1f91376a/af58d68f0b706ae9?hl=en&pli=1